# Using Form Validation Class from Codeigniter to Wordpress

Tags: forms, wordpress, validation, codeigniter

Is there a way to use the Form Validation Class of codeigniter and apply it in wordpress (creating plugin).

Or has anyone tried that already?

Thanks

Comment: i dont know wordpress and dont know its possible to write as plugin , but its possible of course with hacking core

Comment: Potentially, yes, but practically, I'd have to say no. You'd have to rewrite some of the class, because it depends on the full Codeigniter system to work. If you could modify the Form_Validator class to be generic, you could probably use it in a WordPress plugin.

Comment: Good question. I also need this in my project so I think I'll go port the CI field_validation class for use in WP. I'll make a link in github where you can follow it once it's ready.